# how to delete empty rows in delimited csv file in shell scripting

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting, grep

The empty line may contains other than comma also. for example:

file.csv

```
id,date,address
1,2-Oct,fhfhfhf
,,
"","",""
'','',''
```

result:
file.csv

```
id,date,address
1,2-Oct,fhfhfhf
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3):

Simple ***sed*** approach:

```
sed '/^[^-[:alnum:]]/d' file
```

The output:

```
id,date,address
1,2-Oct,fhfhfhf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep "[^,'\"]" file
id,date,address
1,2-Oct,fhfhfhf
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to include more truly representative sample input/output.

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
$ cat file.csv 
id,date,address
1,2-Oct,fhfhfhf
,,
"","",""
'','',''
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F, -v q="[\"']" 'FNR>1{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ t=$i; gsub(q,"",t); if(t){print; next }} next }1' file.csv
id,date,address
1,2-Oct,fhfhfhf
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -F, -v q="[\"']" '                       # call awk set field separator and variable q
        FNR > 1 {                            # if no lines related to current file is greater than 1 then
                   for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) # start loop through fields 
                   {
                     t = $i;                 # assign field contents to variable t
                     gsub(q, "", t);         # global substitution
                                             # suppress single/double quotes
                     if (t) {                # if still variable t has something
                                             # meaning row is not empty so
                       print;                # print current line
                       next                  # go to next line
                     }
                    }
                   next                      # all fields are empty 
                                             # so do not print, 
                                             # go to next line
               }1                            # does default operation print current line/row/record 
                                             # this is for printing header
                     ' file.csv
```